# How to bind or consume the below Web Api to Picker in Xamarin forms cross platform?

Tags: asp.net, api, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm trying to consume the web api in xamarin forms,
Here i want to bind the web api result to the Picker in xamarin forms.
please help.
Below is the web api code:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetNames()
        {

            //Conectionstrings for different databases
            string client1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["client_db1"].ConnectionString;
            string client2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["client_db2"].ConnectionString;
            string client3 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["client_db3"].ConnectionString;


            //Applying the select command for different databases
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(client1);
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select provider_name,Id from Provider_details", con);
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            da1.Fill(ds1);

            con = new SqlConnection(client2);
            da1.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            da1.Fill(ds2);

            con = new SqlConnection(client3);
            da1.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
            DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
            da1.Fill(ds3);

            //Merging the database to select the provider name
            ds1.Merge(ds2);
            ds1.Merge(ds3);

            //return ds;
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ds1);
        }
```

Trying to consume the web api but I'm not getting how to do.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: what is the web api response. can you share that. Can you parse the response in an ObservableCollection<T> ? If so , share that code

Comment: I'm trying the merge the data from different different database using web api. and later consuming the same in Xamarin forms. Please help

Comment: Post the code as @ShubhamTyagi said, unless no one could help you out, be clear at what you are asking for

Comment: I have updated the code , it includes both web api and code for calling the web api in xamarin forms. using the datasets I'll get the providername and its id which im displaying using httpget. the output of the web api is {"Table":[{"provider_name":"Client1","Id":1},{"provider_name":"Client2","Id":102},{"provider_name":"Client3","Id":202}]}.

Comment: After updating the call to web api Im getting an error, please help

Comment: share your `response` model, to set an `ItemSource` you would need it to be something like this
`var cust = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Response>>(customerJsonString);`
Then in Picker you would do `ItemDisplayName="{Binding Name}"`

Comment: "an error" is not a helpful description of the problem.  What is the **specific** error or exception and which line causes it?

Comment: Code for web api is shown please help me in how to call that web api and bind the result to the picker in xamarin forms.

Comment: What error does it throw ?Could you successfully get a response ？

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT, THanks, I have solved the issue. Its working correctly now